# How do I code my website so that my 100% width images adjust size according to screen resolution changing?

Tags: html, resize, resolution, adapt

How do I code my website so that my 100% width images adjust size according to different screen resolutions? For e.g. 1280 x 720.

[Here](http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/mxjgtv/Index.html) is the link to my home page with the images that need resizing according to screen resolution. Look at Lines 119 to 123 for image codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put a height of 700px+ on your images using the **img** in css. Add another class in css saying:

```
.full-width-img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    }
```

Add **class="full-width-img"** to your images you want to have 100% width.

**EDIT**
Remove the **width** qnd **height** from your **img** tags. BEcause right now they are:

```
<img src="images3/motoxmaxres.jpg" class="full-width-img" width="100%" height="" alt="motocross landing">
```

While it should be

```
<img src="images3/motoxmaxres.jpg" class="full-width-img" alt="motocross landing">
```

Comment: Hi Sparky. I have coded in all the "full-width-img" html codes and the CSS code and the images are still not resizing when I adjust the resolution to a lower resolution. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Your images all ahve their own dimensions. Please remove them and use css to format. Check my post, I edited